# CSS grid column width of size "auto" is wider than the image in the column

Tags: css, css-grid

My responsive CSS grid acts oddly in specific dimensions - In the snippet below, I want the image to occupy the first column (of size auto) and span all rows of the grid for that given breakpoint.

However, the column width is unintentionally wider than the actual image for this particular grid height/width. This weird issue leaves undesired white space on the left and right of the image - space which should be allocated to the 2nd column of width 1fr.

Making the grid wider seems to fix this - the first column immediately changes width to match the image width. (For your convenience I made the outer div resizable.)

(Note:

- the image should not stretch, it's height should be the height of the grid and width should scale proportionately
- the grid min-height should be 100% of its parent element)

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
}
.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}
.h-min {
  height: -moz-min-content;
  height: min-content;
}
.max-h-full {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.max-h-fit {
  max-height: -moz-fit-content;
  max-height: fit-content;
}
.min-h-0 {
  min-height: 0px;
}
.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}
.w-\[20cqw\] {
  width: 20cqw;
}
.w-fit {
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
.max-w-full {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.max-w-fit {
  max-width: -moz-fit-content;
  max-width: fit-content;
}
.resize {
  resize: both;
}
.grid-cols-\[auto_1fr\] {
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}
.grid-rows-\[auto_auto_1fr_auto\] {
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto;
}
.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.justify-self-center {
  justify-self: center;
}
.overflow-auto {
  overflow: auto;
}
.rounded {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.rounded-sm {
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
}
.border-4 {
  border-width: 4px;
}
.border {
  border-width: 1px;
}
.border-purple-800 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(107 33 168 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.border-sky-500 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(14 165 233 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.border-neutral-400 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(163 163 163 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.border-green-500 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(34 197 94 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.bg-purple-800 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(107 33 168 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.p-3 {
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
.p-2 {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.p-4 {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.px-4 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
.py-2 {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.text-white {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.\@container {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

@container (min-width: 20rem) {

  .\@xs\:row-span-full {
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
  }

  .\@xs\:h-\[min\(100\%_20cqi\)\] {
    height: min(100% 20cqi);
  }

  .\@xs\:h-\[min\(100\%\2c _20cqi\)\] {
    height: min(100%, 20cqi);
  }

  .\@xs\:w-\[20cqw\] {
    width: 20cqw;
  }

  .\@xs\:grid-cols-\[auto_1fr\] {
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  }

  .\@xs\:grid-rows-\[auto_1fr_auto\] {
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div
  class="resize overflow-auto border border-sky-500 p-2"
  style="width: 405px; height: 160px"
>
  <div class="flex h-full flex-col border border-green-500 @container">
    <h4>Example</h4>
    <div
      class="grid h-full min-h-0 grid-rows-[auto_auto_1fr_auto] rounded border border-neutral-400 @xs:grid-cols-[auto_1fr] @xs:grid-rows-[auto_1fr_auto]"
    >
      <img
        alt="300"
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"
        width="400"
        height="400"
        class="@xs:max-w-[min(100%,_20cqi) max-h-full min-h-0 w-fit max-w-full justify-self-center @xs:row-span-full"
      />
      <div>
        <div class="">Featured product</div>
        <div class="">Nutri Ninja Foodi 6L Multi Cooker</div>
      </div>
      <div class="">$299</div>
      <button
        class="rounded bg-purple-800 px-4 py-2 text-white"
      >
        Buy
      </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**What it looks like:**
[image: column wider than image]
[image: inspect css grid view]

**What I want it to do:**
(achieved here for illustrative purposes by hackily by giving 2nd column div `width: max-content`, but this causes text not to wrap when it gets too long, whereas I want text to wrap.)

[image: column same as image width]
[image: inspect css grid view]

Comment: Sorry if I come across as blunt, but your code doesn't even come close to a [reprex]. Don't just post all your code and see what happens. At least remove all the disabled code and name classes/ids you think we need to investigate.

Comment: Apologies, I've cleaned up the snippet but I'll work on simplifying the classes which I've extracted directly from tailwind which makes it a bit harder to make a reproduce. Hopefully inspecting the relevant elements in the dev console is sufficient to understand the relevant CSS grid issue.

Answer (score 1):

On your grid columns, `grid-template-columns` should use `max-content` for the column you want to auto-size based on the image. So something like this:

```css
.grid-cols-\[auto_1fr\] {
  grid-template-columns: max-content 1fr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The image does not shown because the parent height is fixed and there is no space for image to render, all the other elements occupies spaces.

> So the solution is making the parent height to min-content makes your
> image flexible and responsive

```css
*,
::before,
::after {
  box-sizing: border-box; /* 1 */
  border-width: 0;
  border-style: solid;
}
.product{
  position:relative;
}
.product button{
  width:100%;
  position:absolute;
  bottom:0
}
.flex {
  display: flex;
}
.grid {
  display: grid;
}
.h-full {
  height: 100%;
}
.h-min {
  height: -moz-min-content;
  height: min-content;
}
.max-h-full {
  max-height: 100%;
}
.max-h-fit {
  max-height: -moz-fit-content;
  max-height: fit-content;
}
.min-h-0 {
  min-height: 0px;
}
.w-full {
  width: 100%;
}
.w-\[20cqw\] {
  width: 20cqw;
}
.w-fit {
  width: -moz-fit-content;
  width: fit-content;
}
.max-w-full {
  max-width: 100%;
}
.max-w-fit {
  max-width: -moz-fit-content;
  max-width: fit-content;
}
.resize {
  resize: both;
}
.grid-cols-\[auto_1fr\] {
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}
.grid-rows-\[auto_auto_1fr_auto\] {
  grid-template-rows: auto auto 1fr auto;
}
.flex-col {
  flex-direction: column;
}
.justify-self-center {
  justify-self: center;
}
.overflow-auto {
  overflow: auto;
}
.rounded {
  border-radius: 0.25rem;
}
.rounded-sm {
  border-radius: 0.125rem;
}
.border-4 {
  border-width: 4px;
}
.border {
  border-width: 1px;
}
.border-purple-800 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(107 33 168 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.border-sky-500 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(14 165 233 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.border-neutral-400 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(163 163 163 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.border-green-500 {
  --tw-border-opacity: 1;
  border-color: rgb(34 197 94 / var(--tw-border-opacity));
}
.bg-purple-800 {
  --tw-bg-opacity: 1;
  background-color: rgb(107 33 168 / var(--tw-bg-opacity));
}
.p-3 {
  padding: 0.75rem;
}
.p-2 {
  padding: 0.5rem;
}
.p-4 {
  padding: 1rem;
}
.px-4 {
  padding-left: 1rem;
  padding-right: 1rem;
}
.py-2 {
  padding-top: 0.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.5rem;
}

.text-white {
  --tw-text-opacity: 1;
  color: rgb(255 255 255 / var(--tw-text-opacity));
}

.\@container {
  container-type: inline-size;
}

@container (min-width: 20rem) {

  .\@xs\:row-span-full {
    grid-row: 1 / -1;
  }

  .\@xs\:h-\[min\(100\%_20cqi\)\] {
    height: min(100% 20cqi);
  }

  .\@xs\:h-\[min\(100\%\2c _20cqi\)\] {
    height: min(100%, 20cqi);
  }

  .\@xs\:w-\[20cqw\] {
    width: 20cqw;
  }

  .\@xs\:grid-cols-\[auto_1fr\] {
    grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  }

  .\@xs\:grid-rows-\[auto_1fr_auto\] {
    grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  }
}
```

```html
<div
  class="resize overflow-auto border border-sky-500 p-2"
  style="width: 500px; height: 500px"
> 
  <div class="flex h-full flex-col border border-green-500 @container">
    <h4>Example</h4>
    <div
      class="grid h-full min-h-0 grid-cols-[auto_1fr] rounded border border-neutral-400 @xs:grid-cols-[auto_1fr] @xs:grid-rows-[auto_1fr_auto]"
    >
      <img
        alt="300"
        src="https://via.placeholder.com/300"
        class="img"
      />
      <div class='product'>
        <div class="">Featured product</div>
        <div class="product_name">
          <span>Nutri Ninja Foodi 6L Multi Cooker Multiple line added</span>
        </div>
        <div class="">$299</div>
      <button
        class="rounded bg-purple-800 px-4 py-2 text-white"
      >
        Buy
      </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks but my issue isn't that the image isn't showing but that the column width which the image is in is wider than the picture size - for example in your code, if you resize the width of the parent div with the blue border to around 390px and height under 200px, the left and right of the image still has white space due to the column being wider.

Comment: Just remove all the image classes and new img class with width:100%. So the white space will removed

Comment: Thanks Yuvaraj, I didn't do a good job explaining - I've added pictures of the desired CSS grid behaviour to the question. Do you know how I can achieve this behaviour? The image classes make the image height equal the height of the grid and the width to scale proportionately to its height, which is what I want.

Comment: Would you update the code currently are you using!

Comment: @StephenKoo i made those changes you asked (text warp also included), waiting for your confirmation

Comment: Thank you Yuvaraj, the image is now behaving exactly like it should be, but the text is using `white-space: nowrap` & `overflow-hidden` which is the hack I used. I want the text to wrap to multiple lines if it gets longer than the full width of the grid column

Comment: Finally reached your requirement, @StephenKoo I changed the code.

Comment: Still no quite what I'm looking for, but I appreciate the effort. Your solution fixes the initial problem but breaks desired pre-existing behaviour, specifically:
- The green border box (the flex container) should be take up the remaining height of the parent container (blue border box)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/251057/discussion-between-stephen-koo-and-yuvaraj-m).

Comment: Awaiting for your confirmation @StephenKoo